# Translate of an ideal by $a$ coincides with the ideal iff  $a \in I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How  can I show the following?

> Show that, if $a$ and $b$ are elements of a ring $R$ and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $$a+I=0+I \iff a \in I$$

I am so interested to know the proof.Thanks and good night all!

Comment: Note that this is really a statement about groups (the underlying additive abelian group of the ring, here): if $H < G$ then $aH = H$ if and only if $a \in H$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Hence the title using the word "Translates" to convey the idea of cosets. =)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the definition of $a+I$:

$$a+I=\{a+r\mid r\in I\}$$

Clearly, we have that
$$0+I=\{0+r\mid r\in I\}=\{r\mid r\in I\}=I.$$

Because $I$ is an ideal, $0\in I$. Thus, for any $a\in R$, one of the elements of $a+I$ is $a+0=a$. If we knew that $a+I=0+I=I$, then $a$ is an element of $I$.

Now try showing the opposite direction on your own :)

Comment: Beat me to it. But, I was also editing the question! +1